# svn add or include ignored files into the working tree

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I ignored some files to be committed in svn before

```
svn changelist ignore-on-commit file1.c file2.c
```

Now I want to include it into the working copy. Please anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `TortoiseSVN` is using `ignore-on-commit changelist` to [exclude items from the commit list](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore), just [remove](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html) `changelist` label from these files:

```
   svn changelist --remove file1.c file2.c
```